# Showing $T(\int_{\Omega}f(\cdot,y)dy)=\int_{\Omega}T(f(\cdot,y))dy$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set, $D(\Omega\times\Omega)=C^{\infty}_c(\Omega\times\Omega)$ (i.e. the smooth function with compact support in $\Omega$) and $T\in D'(\Omega)$ be a distribution, i.e. an element of the dual of $D(\Omega)$. Let $f\in D(\Omega\times \Omega)$ we have $f(\cdot,y)$ (for a fixed $y$) and $\int_{\Omega}f(\cdot,y)dy$ that are test functions. I have to prove that $T(\int_{\Omega}f(\cdot,y)dy)=\int_{\Omega}T(f(\cdot,y))dy$ but I don't really know in which direction to go.

Comment: Can you define your terms carefully and precisely?  How are we supposed to know what $T, D,$ and $\Omega$ are?

Comment: The quick and dirty way of doing this is to approximate the integral by Riemann sums. However, a more conceptual way is to see this as a particular case of Fubini's Theorem for distributions. See, e.g., https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028

Comment: yes this is like Fubini's theorem